# Why send an empty string on an interval to a WebSocket server

Tags: javascript, websocket

The following snippet comes from a js file that uses the native WebSocket api to stream images. The file is minified and uglified, I don't have access to the original code.

```
setInterval(function () { n && n.send("")},
NETWORK.websocketSendMessage)
```

n is an object initialized to a native WebSocket connection object that streams base64 encoded jpegs.
The interval time is a constant set to 1000ms.

Supposedly this triggers the server to send a set of frames every second, which will asynchronously trigger the onmessage handler set on the ws object.

I'm trying to understand why this interval is necessary - in my understanding using a WebSocket should prevent the need to use such primitive polling in the first place (albeit I assume this would obviously be faster than actual polling with a new http request every second).

It shouldn't be that the client updates the server that it would like to **continue** recieving content. Rather, a more logical approach in my mind would be announcing when the content should **stop**.

Could this be a technique to control ram? The onmessage handler seems to tear down a parser for the data every time it triggers - could this in turn free up the ram used by the streamed files by eventual gc?

Keep in mind this could be ancient legacy code - so perhaps understanding browser quirks could be insightful.

Comment: It could be an internal workaround, for example because the socket server drops idle connections after some timeout…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [keepalive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_keepalive) is a message sent by one device to another to check that the link between the two is operating, or to prevent the link from being broken. you can read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive